# How to print contents of ctypes string buffer

Tags: python, ctypes

I am creating a string buffer using ctypes library in python.
Now if I have to print contents of this string buffer later when it has been written, how will i achieve that in python?

```
import ctypes
init_size = 256
pBuf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(init_size)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.value` and `.raw` properties to access and manipulate them. This is documented far down in [this part of the `ctypes` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes.create_string_buffer#fundamental-data-types).

Here is some of the example code from that section:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> p = create_string_buffer(3)            # create a 3 byte buffer, initialized to NUL bytes
>>> print(sizeof(p), repr(p.raw))
3 b'\x00\x00\x00'
>>> p = create_string_buffer(b"Hello")     # create a buffer containing a NUL terminated string
>>> print(sizeof(p), repr(p.raw))
6 b'Hello\x00'
>>> print(repr(p.value))
b'Hello'
>>> p = create_string_buffer(b"Hello", 10) # create a 10 byte buffer
>>> print(sizeof(p), repr(p.raw))
10 b'Hello\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> p.value = b"Hi"
>>> print(sizeof(p), repr(p.raw))
10 b'Hi\x00lo\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Python Ctypes docs at:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html

You should be able to print  the string buffer value using the .value object property ie:

```
print repr(pBuf.value)
```

Or if you want to get a bit fancy with the io you can use something like:

```
print "pBuff: %s" % pBuf.value
```